# Terraform How to use for each values from one resource in another resource

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I am trying to create users in terraform cloud based off a simple csv, structured like so:

```
email,access_level
test@gmail.com,readonly
test2@gmail.come,owners
```

I can create users easily enough using the following resource block:

```
locals {
  users_csv = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/users.csv"))

}


resource "tfe_organization_membership" "users_csv" {
  for_each = { for r in local.users_csv : r.email => r }

  organization  = var.ppl_organisation
  email = each.value.email
}
```

However, if I want to add them to teams then I need the "id" output from the above resource into the below resource:

```
resource "tfe_team_organization_member" "readonly_member" {
  for_each = { for r in local.read_only : r.email => r }

  team_id = each.value.access_level == "readonly" ? each.value.access_level : local.readonly_id
  organization_membership_id = "${tfe_organization_membership.users_csv.id}"
}
```

Is there a way to pass this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try with `organization_membership_id =  tfe_organization_membership.users_csv[each.key].id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first thing I'd do here is to factor out the projection of your CSV data from a list to a map, like this:

```
locals {
  users_csv = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/users.csv"))
  users     = { for r in local.users_csv : r.email => r }
}
```

By defining `local.users` like this we can make it more concise to refer to that value multiple times elsewhere in the config:

```
resource "tfe_organization_membership" "users_csv" {
  for_each = local.users

  organization = var.ppl_organisation
  email        = each.value.email
}

resource "tfe_team_organization_member" "readonly_member" {
  for_each = local.users

  team_id = (
    each.value.access_level == "readonly" ?
    each.value.access_level :
    local.readonly_id
  )
  organization_membership_id = tfe_organization_membership.users_csv[each.key].id
}
```

Any resource that has `for_each` set is represented in expressions as a map of objects whose keys are the same as the `for_each` input map, so the `tfe_organization_membership.users_csv[each.key]` expression refers to an object representation of the corresponding instance of the other resource, correlating by the map keys.

Comment: Hi thanks for this reply, that sorted what I was trying to do perfectly.
Much appreciated!